# Replace special characters in a column using SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a dataframe which contains a column. In this column I have String something like below

```
 <a href="mailto:NO@EMAIL.COM">NO@EMAIL.COM</a>
<a href="mailto:MICAHELBAHOU@YAHO">MICAHELSAM@YAHOO.COM</a>…
```

But I just need the below values in my column

```
NO@EMAIL.COM
MICAHELSAM@YAHOO.COM
```

I tried using [substring_index](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html), Like below

```
df$EMAIL_ADDR <- SparkR::substring_index(df$EMAIL_ADDR, "<", -1)
df$EMAIL_ADDR <- SparkR::substring_index(df$EMAIL_ADDR, ">", 1)
```

But the column values does not change. I tried with different int values as well.

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using basic regular expressions:

```
df <- data.frame(email_addr=c(
    '<a href="mailto:NO@EMAIL.COM">NO@EMAIL.COM</a>',
    '<a href="mailto:MICAHELBAHOU@YAHO">MICAHELSAM@YAHOO.COM</a>'
))

sdf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df)

email <- alias(regexp_extract(sdf$email_addr, "(?<=\\>)(.*)(?=\\<)", 1), "email")

select(sdf, email) %>% head()
##                  email
## 1         NO@EMAIL.COM
## 2 MICAHELSAM@YAHOO.COM

withColumn(sdf, "email", email)
## DataFrame[email_addr:string, email:string]
```

Using `HiveContext` and [XPath UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF):

```
hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
hdf <- createDataFrame(hiveContext, df)

xpath_email <- alias(expr("xpath(email_addr, '/a/text()')"), "email")

select(hdf, xpath_email) %>% head()
##                  email
## 1         NO@EMAIL.COM
## 2 MICAHELSAM@YAHOO.COM


withColumn(hdf, "email", xpath_email)
## DataFrame[email_addr:string, email:array<string>]
```

Note that XPath returns an array. If you want individual elements you can `explode`:

```
withColumn(hdf, "email", explode(xpath_email))
```

or `getItem`:

```
withColumn(hdf, "email", getItem(xpath_email, 0L))
```